# Clicking link using beautifulsoup in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

In mechanize we click links either by using follow_link or click_link. Is there a similar kind of thing in beautiful soup to click a link on a web page?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`BeautifulSoup` is an HTML **parser**.

Further discussion really depends on the concrete situation you are in and the complexity of the particular web page.

If you need to interact with a web-page: submit forms, click buttons, scroll etc - you need to use a tool that utilizes a real browser, like [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/).

In certain situations, for example, if there is no javascript involved in submitting a form, [`mechanize`](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) would also work for you.

And, sometimes you can handle it by simply following the link with [`urllib2`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) or [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/).

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering if it is possible to modify the link using python as we do using inspect element in browsers? I tried using mechanize. The link got modified as it appeared after printing it but when clicked it still opened the same page.

Comment: @user3286661 ok, could you show the code you are using? What is the purpose of it? Thanks.

Comment: Oh yes! I have posted a question already. Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23677442/changing-the-link-in-python-mechanize

Comment: @user3286661 gotcha, will take a look at your particular mechanize issue. I also don't think there is smth to add for the current question.

Comment: @alecxe can you please help out with a problem I have with beautiful soup?

Answer (score 0):

print(soup.find('h1',class_='pdp_product_title'))
does not give any result
`<div class="pr2-sm css-1ou6bb2"><h2 class="headline-5-small pb1-sm d-sm-ib css-1ppcdci" data-test="product-sub-title">Women's Shoe</h2><h1 id="pdp_product_title" class="headline-2 css-zis9ta" data-test="product-title">Nike Air Force 1 Shadow</h1></div>`