# Use of Beautiful Soup to load more data and navigating through pages

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

So I want to use beautifulsoup4 to query information about waterloo professors in ratemyprof. The data needs to be taken from a navbar where you continually need to press Load More to load more data.

Furthermore, on inspecting the load more button, it links to a javascript function. How do I write code to continuously load more till it cannot?
Here is a snippet of what it looks like upon inspection of button:  [Load More Inspection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2V0mt.png)

Can someone please help me write the loop to extract info from this page: "http://www.ratemyprofessors.com/search.jsp?queryBy=schoolId&schoolName=University+of+Waterloo&schoolID=1490&queryoption=TEACHER"

Comment: "_Can someone please help me write the loop_" Yes, but only if you show us what you'd done to solve this problem thus far. Please know that SO is not a code writing service. We help you debug your code, not write it for you.

Comment: Hello sorry I'm new to programming in general.
https://i.imgur.com/5QgVIgr.png
This is as far as I've written. But the output's a bit weird.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/hKWOsN0.png
This is when I noticed the javascript on the load more button

Comment: Please. Information goes in the question, not comments.

Comment: so as you can see, it's giving me a template, not what I wanted at all

Comment: you shouldn't be posting links, you should be updating the question with your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy.

using `evaluateJavaScript` grab more data which js load.

or [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) may help you.

see also [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23679480/clicking-link-using-beautifulsoup-in-python/23679526#23679526)